# Google OAuth Electron WebView deprecation

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, electron

In reference to: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

In this page, it is clearly stated that: "**On April 20, 2017, we will start blocking OAuth requests using web-views for all OAuth clients on platforms where viable alternatives exist.**"

Does this affect Electron WebViews as well? If it does, can you point me to any samples?

Comment: I'd care too much about it, since Google guaranteed that they'll block only the platform has an alternative. Have you tried contacting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Google is indeed deprecating Electron WebViews. There are multiple solutions to this:

- Open google sign-in page in user's browser and :

  (1) Setup a HttpListener similar to this https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthDesktopApp

  (2) Specify custom URI scheme in the redirect_url to open your app after login. (This might open notifications/popus in the user's browser)
- Use [AppAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) to perform login to Google