# How to use OAuth2 token with gmail in a WebView in Electron?

Tags: google-api, electron, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm working on an Electron application that needs to render Gmail in a WebView. I've got to the point where I can authenticate via OAuth2 and get a token, but don't know what to do with it from there.

Fundamentally, I need a way to send the token to Google in a way that then loads the regular GMail web interface. Is this possible?

All wisdom appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the usage of the Gmail api.

> I need a way to send the token to Google in a way that then loads the regular GMail web interface

The gmail api allows you to access a users Gmail account the data is returned in json format.   If you want this displayed or formated in anyway that will be up to you.

There is no way to pass a Oauth token to anything that will load the gmail website only google can load that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I have misunderstood. The drive for this change comes from this: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html and if you check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705752/google-oauth-electron-webview-deprecation you'll see that surfacing the OAuth flow up to the native browser is what Google wanted.  

I hope you're wrong on the last point, but it is what I fear...

Comment: Both of those articles are several years old and speak of the Oauth2 flow they have nothing to do with Gmail or the gmail api.   Your not going to be able to open the gmail website using a token you created for your application